# Simple app that shows pages depending on an API built with a static site framework

Tags: reactjs, api, next.js, gatsby, react-three-fiber

I created a project with React, but now I'm thinking of SEO

My project is very simple, although it shows 3D Models using React Three Fiber

But it also shows pages that are defined depending on some videos obtained from Vimeo (using an API), making the site a little dynamic, since we don't previously know which pages will be shown

The question is, can this site be successfully built using Gatsby, as a Static Sites Framework, or do I have to use an SSR Framework like Vercel's Next, because of the pages that will be generated from an API

Comment: It seems like you are mixing up the use cases for SSR vs SSG. Anything rendered server-side will be fine SEO wise as the server is generating everything (or most things) needed and sending mainly just HTML instead of all the Javascript to render and run a CSR app. Are you using Gatsby currently? If so Gatsby is fine SEO wise. Check out this for more info: https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/how-to/adding-common-features/seo/

Comment: I just want to know if my project can be successfully built using Gatsby, knowing that is a little dynamic since there are pages that are shown depending on the search on the Vimeo API. But the project works with React and Gatsby, I already did it (it worked with npm run dev/start, didn't test it on a cloud hosting). Don't know if I'm pushing the boundaries here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes Gatsby is a good solution. If you realize in the future that you might need to be re-building the app a little more than you are comfortable with, then you can re-hydrate the browser on the users end to query data that you get from an api. This keeps the benefits of SSG (speed, robustness, and SEO), but adds some flexibility and dynamic nature to your application. You can set it up with the Gatsby docs (which are great for any problems you might have with Gatsby in the future). Extra info below: https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/config-files/gatsby-ssr